# How to remove class colorbox if display:none

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I try to remove class colorbox when style `display:none`

il someone can help me, thank you

HTML

```
    <li class="portfolio-item" style="display: none;">
    <div class="item-image">
        <a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.monsite.fr/IMG_1423.jpg""></a>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="portfolio-item" style=" ">
    <div class="item-image">
        <a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.monsite.fr/IMG_1424.jpg""></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".portfolio-item .item-image a[href$='.jpg']").colorbox({
    rel:"group2",
    maxWidth:"80%", 
    maxHeight:"80%"});


    if($('.portfolio-item').css('display') == 'none'){ 
       $('.portfolio-item').find(".item-image a[href$='.jpg']").removeClass('colorbox'); 
    } 

});
```

**Edit**

Thanks for your help, but I tried this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".portfolio-item .item-image a[href$='.jpg']").colorbox({
       rel:"group2",
    maxWidth:"95%", 
    maxHeight:"95%"});  

    $('li.portfolio-item').filter(':hidden').map(function() {
        $(this).find('a.colorbox').removeClass('colorbox');
    });     
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Your markup isn't valid, the anchors all have two quotes at the end, making the entire HTML invalid, and selecting anything with jQuery damn near impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your href attributes are surrounded by one set of `"`:

```
<a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.monsite.fr/IMG_1423.jpg"></a>
```

And try using the `:hidden` pseudo selector to detect if an element has `display:none;`:

```
if($('.portfolio-item:hidden').length){ 
   $('.portfolio-item').find(".item-image a[href$='.jpg']").removeClass('colorbox'); 
}
```

It may be a better approach to use a `.each` loop on the portfolio items:

```
$('.portfolio-item:hidden').each(function(){
    $(this).find(".item-image a[href$='.jpg']").removeClass('colorbox');
}
```

[jQuery :hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your markup. Then you can do the following:-

```
$('li.portfolio-item').filter(':hidden').map(function() {
  $(this).find('a.colorbox').removeClass('colorbox');
});
```